# How to pass foo='bar baz' to command from cli arguments

Tags: bash, args

Here's a stripped down example of what I'm trying to do.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x

echo "$@"
```

calling it with

```
bash script -vv --foo='bar baz'
```

yields

```
+ echo -vv 'foo=bar baz'
-vv foo=bar baz
```

Note that the + line (i.e the debug line) is putting single quotes around the entire foo=bar baz.  I need it to pass

```
foo='bar baz'
```

not

```
'foo=bar baz'
```

I have tried several iterations to no avail.
Is there a way to get it to pass the former?

Comment: The equivalent in Python would be asking why the shell changes `r'\hello\world'` to `'\\hello\\world'` when the value is passed through `repr()`.

Comment: One thing I would suggest: If you have a command you can successfully run _manually_, on the command line, that uses `foo="bar baz"` as an argument somewhere, run `set -x` in your command-line session, and compare the working command logged there to the one invoked by your script. You'll see that the transformation to `'foo=bar baz'` happens even _every_ context, including manual command-line invocations.

Comment: (BTW, I'm using Python analogies for explanatory purposes because it's a language I notice you have experience with from your SO profile; if it's not the best choice for the purpose, though, let me know).

Comment: Try running `echo -vv foo='bar baz'` -- you'll see that `echo` generates the exact same output that it provides from `echo -vv 'foo=bar baz'`. Granted, `echo` is a bad example (its behavior is very ambiguous), but you'll see the same thing with `printf '%q\n' -vv foo='bar baz'` and `printf '%q\n' -vv 'foo=bar baz'` -- and `printf %q` has a unique representation for each possible string (which is to say: absent currently-unknown bugs, no two strings with different values will come out of the `%q` transform the same way).

Comment: If you want to convince yourself of the above, use `strace -f` to trace execution of your script, and look at the `execve` syscall that's being used to invoke the program you're starting; you'll see that `strace -f bash -c 'someprogram foo="bar baz"'` and `strace -f bash -c 'someprogram "foo=bar baz"` call `someprogram` with the exact same argument list -- not just semantically-identical, but _actually represented with the same bytes in memory_, and thus literally impossible to distinguish.

Comment: ...to reiterate: I'm assuming you asked this because you have a real problem, and decided that the quotes being changed were the cause. **They cannot possibly be.** Thus, to let us help you, post a question (ideally a new one) with a [mre] for the actual problem you were trying to solve before going down this rabbit hole, so we can try to figure out the actual cause of your issue.

Comment: @Charles Duffy Thanks for all of your explanations so far.  This is the most minimal reproducible example I could come up with.  The actual bash script where I need to implement a solution is significantly more complicated.  Besides lots of env vars and buiding up params, the only relevant difference from my mvp here is that rather than echo, there's a python program that I don't control and thus cannot change.

Comment: Understood. However, to repeat myself once again, *the Python program cannot possibly tell the difference between the two commands*. To convince yourself of this, run the following: `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv[1] == sys.argv[2])' --foo='bar baz' '--foo=bar baz'`; you'll see it emits `True`, meaning the two strings are equal to each other. Thus, there **must** be an additional difference.

Comment: ...I wonder if you might be coming from a Windows background? In the Windows world, parsing a command line is done by the program being run (typically with a default implementation by the libc, but it's possible to override); thus, that program knows exactly how the command line invoking it was constructed. That's not true in UNIX: Instead of passing a single command line, programs are passed an array of C strings (hence the `main(int argc, char[][] argv)` signature); they don't know if that array of strings was generated from a single command line, much less what the command line _is_.

Comment: BTW, I feel like we're talking past each other a bit. I'm presenting what is as far as I can tell (and I've been doing software development on UNIX professionally for more than half my life now) is incontrovertible proof that the underlying cause of your problem is not the thing you diagnosed it to be and then asked about here, and you seem to be ignoring it, rather than offering a refutation. Could I ask you to walk me through what part of the argument I'm jumping over or otherwise failing to make?

Comment: If I pass the args directly to the python script that I don't control, everything works fine.  When I pass them to my bash script which passes them (along with other args) to the python script, it's all broken.  This is what I'm trying to figure out a way around.  The bash script is necessary in order to build up the additional args.

Comment: Please use `strace` as I suggested earlier to collect the `execve` calls made in both working and broken cases. If your question is accurate and the working code parses the string `--foo='bar baz'` as shell syntax (a process which **removes the quotes** after using them to decide where to split on whitespace and how to interpret the characters within) the two will be identical, but perhaps the question's statements and actual behavior don't match up.

Comment: ...or, instead of `strace`, you could replace the Python script you don't control with a new one that just runs `import sys; print(repr(sys.argv))`; that should be quite enough to demonstrate an **actual difference in behavior** in a way that people who aren't you can observe.

Comment: To be clear: Your original question is like saying that there's a 3rd-party Python library you're using where `thatlibrary.foo('hello')` works, but `thatlibrary.foo("hello")` doesn't work. That's impossible, because in Python `'foo'` and `"foo"` are just two different ways of writing the same string -- just as in bash, `--foo='bar baz'` and `'--foo=bar baz'` are two different ways of writing the same string at well. That's why I'm so repetitively pressing you for some way to show a reproducer other people can run that demonstrates different behavior.

Comment: ...if your _real_ working command isn't using `--foo='bar baz'` but instead is using `"--foo='bar baz'"`, for example, that would be a place there _existed_ a real difference, but the question was phrased in a way that hid it.

Answer (score 1):

`set -x` *doesn't* change quotes in your arguments: `foo='bar baz'` and `'foo=bar baz'` are two different ways of writing the same string. Any program you pass these arguments to will be given the C string `"foo=bar baz"` (those double quotes being C syntax, not literal content) in the relevant position in its argv array. Note that there are no `'`s anywhere in that string.

This is true because quoting is evaluated on a *per-character basis* by all POSIX shells (a class in which bash is a member); and syntactic quotes are removed prior to actual execution, thus leaving only literal data.

In `foo='bar baz'`, you have `foo=` in an unquoted context and `bar baz` in a single-quoted context being concatenated together into a single string.

In `'foo=bar baz'`, the shell's debug output shows you a single string containing the results of that operation.

These strings are identical; they just happen to be described using different syntax. Consequently, it is impossible to have any bug caused by the distinction between these two representations, because the value they cause to be passed to the invoked program is exactly identical; **the called program cannot tell which one was used, and thus cannot change its behavior based on the distinction. Thus, no bug based on this distinction is possible.**

Comment: I understand why it's doing it.  I'm trying to find a way to pass it in the desired format so that the command I'm passing it to can work.

Comment: @senorsmile It's not possible to write a command that can differentiate between being passed a parameter `foo='bar baz'` and `'foo=bar baz'`. If you e.g. need to pass literal single quotes, then that's a different question with a different answer.

Comment: @senorsmile, **there is no difference**. Just like a Python function can't tell if you passed it `r'\hello\world'` or `'\\hello\\world'` or `"\\hello\\world"` because the way all those values are stored in memory is exactly the same, nothing you call from your bash script can possibly know if it was passed `foo='bar baz'` or `'foo=bar baz'`; and consequently, there cannot possibly be any bug caused by the distinction.

Comment: @senorsmile, ...if you think you _have_ such a bug, ask a question that demonstrates it.

Comment: @senorsmile, ...to explain it differently, we have a lot of Q&A entries here from people who try to do something like `subprocess.run(['someprogram', '--arg="value here"'])` and are surprised when they get errors from the program they're running, even though `someprogram --arg="value here"` works fine in bash. Those errors are because shell quotes are syntactic, and must not be made literal; the correct thing is `subprocess.run(['someprogram', '--arg=value here'])`, and that's exactly what the shell transforms `someprogram --arg="value here"` into when it's parsing and running that command.